# How to remove user from Azure Ad , Using Microsoft Graph Client SDK?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using using Microsoft.Graph, How do I remove the User from Azure AD using Microsoft Graph Client SDK?
I dont see any documentation or sample code around this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Your question is lacking sufficient detail to help.

Comment: I dont understand what more information you need on this ? :(

Comment: Such as what SDK are you using. Is that .NET SDK?

Comment: Microsoft Graph .NET sdk

Comment: await graphClient.Users["dmitry@abc.com"].Request().DeleteAsync();

using this I see a Forbidden error. Is it that it is not supported via graph

Answer (score 1):

Making calls in the Graph SDKs follows the recipe of 1) defining the path, 2) building the request and 3) specifying the verb.

First, you build up a request by specifying the path to a given resource or collection of resources. The calling pattern here mirrors the REST API.

**REST**: `graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/dmitry@abc.com`

**.NET SDK**: `graphClient.Users["dmitry@abc.com"]`

Next, you build the request and specify the verb.

`await graphClient.Users["dmitry@abc.com"].Request().DeleteAsync();`

Note that for operations that create resources, you would pass an [object representing the resource as an argument](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/collections.md#adding-to-a-collection) to the `AddAsync` or `PutAsync` methods of the request object.

Comment: I am getting a FORBIDDEN error while deleting the user. I have already assigned all the permissions.

Comment: Where did you define these permissions (Azure portal or apps.dev.microsoft.com)? You will need to make sure that you've configured the correct permissions and are calling from that "mode". For instance, make sure you are not calling the API in app-only mode when the permissions are only set up for delegated callers. Also, please note that the user principal you are deleting exists in your tenant ("dmitry@abc.com" is just an example).

Comment: I am creating the graph client on application level and permissions are applied.

Comment: Can you confirm that the token is valid? Can you make the request successfully via REST (or in a REST client like Postman)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample for CRUD operations on the user/groups in Azure Active Directory using Microsoft.Graph .NET SDK. You will need to register the application in Azure and have to provide **clientid** and **client secret** for the same in web.config file. Don't forget to add required permissions for the application.

**link:** https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample